# How can I display all of the question together with their own choices in my view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this response array.

```
[
   {
      "id":16,
      "question":"Who is this message for?",
      "duration":60,
      "choices":[
         {
            "id":61,
            "question_id":16,
            "choice":"guests"
         },
         {
            "id":62,
            "question_id":16,
            "choice":"Eskaya"
         },
         {
            "id":63,
            "question_id":16,
            "choice":"local artists"
         },
         {
            "id":64,
            "question_id":16,
            "choice":"conference attendees"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":17,
      "question":"What is displayed in the lobby? ",
      "duration":60,
      "choices":[
         {
            "id":65,
            "question_id":17,
            "choice":"plush furniture"
         },
         {
            "id":66,
            "question_id":17,
            "choice":"the 24-hour restaurant"
         },
         {
            "id":67,
            "question_id":17,
            "choice":"the main conference rooms"
         },
         {
            "id":68,
            "question_id":17,
            "choice":"art from various local artists "
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":18,
      "question":"What type of establishment is Eskaya?",
      "duration":60,
      "choices":[
         {
            "id":69,
            "question_id":18,
            "choice":"a hotel"
         },
         {
            "id":70,
            "question_id":18,
            "choice":"a pool area"
         },
         {
            "id":71,
            "question_id":18,
            "choice":"a restaurant"
         },
         {
            "id":72,
            "question_id":18,
            "choice":"a conference center"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to display it on my view like this:

```
1.Who is this message for?
  guests
  Eskaya
  local artists
  conference attendees

2.What is displayed in the lobby? 
  plush furniture
  the 24-hour restaurant
  the main conference rooms
  art from various local artists
```

Something like that.

Here is the code and output that I currently have.

```js
var questionList = '';
var radioChoices = '';

for (var i = 0; i < scenario_question[0].questions.length; i++) {
  questionList = questionList + '<p id="display_question_scenario">' +(i+1)+"."+" "+scenario_question[0].questions[i].question;


  for (var x = 0; x < scenario_question[0].questions[i].choices.length; x++) {
    radioChoices = radioChoices + '<input type="radio" name="answer_choice" value="' + scenario_question[0].questions[i].choices[x].id + '"><label>' + scenario_question[0].questions[i].choices[x].choice + '</label>';
  }

}

  $('.listening_question_scenario').html(questionList);
  $('#question_choices').html(radioChoices);
```

```html
<div id="listening_choices_wrapper">

  <div class="listening_question_scenario">
    <p id="display_question_scenario">
     
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="question_choices" class="listening_question_choice">
  
  </div>

</div>
```

The output that I am having is:

```
1. Who is this message for?

2. What is displayed in the lobby? 

3. What type of establishment is Eskaya?

guests
Eskaya
local artists
conference attendees
plush furniture
the 24-hour restaurant
the main conference rooms
art from various local artists
a hotel 
a pool area
a restaurant
a conference center
```

What is I am doing wrong? instead of displaying the choices in their own questions, it is just displaying like that. Can anyone help me on correcting me. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code you are appending `htmls` in two different variable so that's why results comes separately . Instead you can append `divs` inside one variable and modify your code according to that.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var questionList = '';
var scenario_question = [{
    "id": 16,
    "questions": "Who is this message for?",
    "duration": 60,
    "choices": [{
        "id": 61,
        "question_id": 16,
        "choice": "guests"
      },
      {
        "id": 62,
        "question_id": 16,
        "choice": "Eskaya"
      },
      {
        "id": 63,
        "question_id": 16,
        "choice": "local artists"
      },
      {
        "id": 64,
        "question_id": 16,
        "choice": "conference attendees"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "questions": "What is displayed in the lobby? ",
    "duration": 60,
    "choices": [{
        "id": 65,
        "question_id": 17,
        "choice": "plush furniture"
      },
      {
        "id": 66,
        "question_id": 17,
        "choice": "the 24-hour restaurant"
      },
      {
        "id": 67,
        "question_id": 17,
        "choice": "the main conference rooms"
      },
      {
        "id": 68,
        "question_id": 17,
        "choice": "art from various local artists "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "questions": "What type of establishment is Eskaya?",
    "duration": 60,
    "choices": [{
        "id": 69,
        "question_id": 18,
        "choice": "a hotel"
      },
      {
        "id": 70,
        "question_id": 18,
        "choice": "a pool area"
      },
      {
        "id": 71,
        "question_id": 18,
        "choice": "a restaurant"
      },
      {
        "id": 72,
        "question_id": 18,
        "choice": "a conference center"
      }
    ]
  }
]
//loop through json array
$(scenario_question).each(function(index, value) {
  //append value (questions)
  questionList += '<div class="display_question_scenario">' + (index + 1) + "." + " " + value.questions
  //create divs
  questionList += '<div id="question_choices" class="listening_question_choice">'
  var count = index + 1;
  $(value.choices).each(function(index, value) {
    //append choices
    questionList += '<input type="radio" name="answer_choice' + count + '" value="' + value.id + '"><label>' + value.choice + '</label><br>';
  })
  //close div
  questionList += '</div></div>'
})

$('.listening_question_scenario').html(questionList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="listening_choices_wrapper">
  <div class="listening_question_scenario">
    <div id="display_question_scenario">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = [{
    "id": 16,
    "question": "Who is this message for?",
    "duration": 60,
    "choices": [{
        "id": 61,
        "question_id": 16,
        "choice": "guests"
      },
      {
        "id": 62,
        "question_id": 16,
        "choice": "Eskaya"
      },
      {
        "id": 63,
        "question_id": 16,
        "choice": "local artists"
      },
      {
        "id": 64,
        "question_id": 16,
        "choice": "conference attendees"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "question": "What is displayed in the lobby? ",
    "duration": 60,
    "choices": [{
        "id": 65,
        "question_id": 17,
        "choice": "plush furniture"
      },
      {
        "id": 66,
        "question_id": 17,
        "choice": "the 24-hour restaurant"
      },
      {
        "id": 67,
        "question_id": 17,
        "choice": "the main conference rooms"
      },
      {
        "id": 68,
        "question_id": 17,
        "choice": "art from various local artists "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "question": "What type of establishment is Eskaya?",
    "duration": 60,
    "choices": [{
        "id": 69,
        "question_id": 18,
        "choice": "a hotel"
      },
      {
        "id": 70,
        "question_id": 18,
        "choice": "a pool area"
      },
      {
        "id": 71,
        "question_id": 18,
        "choice": "a restaurant"
      },
      {
        "id": 72,
        "question_id": 18,
        "choice": "a conference center"
      }
    ]
  }
]
var questionList = '';

for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  questionList = questionList + '<p id="display_question_scenario">' + (i + 1) + "." + " " + s[i].question;

  for (let x = 0; x < s[i].choices.length; x++) {
    questionList = questionList + '<input type="radio" name="answer_choice" value="' + s[i].choices[x].id + '"><label>' + s[i].choices[x].choice + '</label>';
  }

}
questionList += '</p>'
$('.listening_question_scenario').html(questionList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="listening_choices_wrapper">

  <div class="listening_question_scenario">
    <p id="display_question_scenario">

    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="question_choices" class="listening_question_choice">

  </div>

</div>
```